# React CSSTransition not working?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, transition

I'm trying to have a login component fade in when the page is loaded and then fade out when the new component is rendered. No fading happens at all, it just appears. I read in other posts you need a key, but I have no idea what the key value would be in this instance?

```
return (
        <div className="box2">
                            <CSSTransition
                                transitionName="example"
                                transitionAppear={true}
                                transitionAppearTimeout={500}
                                transitionEnter={false}
                                transitionLeave={false}>
                        <Login/>
                            </CSSTransition>
                            <Button bsStyle="primary" 
    onClick={this.changeView}>SUBMIT</Button>
                        </div>
);
```

CSS:

```
example-enter {
    opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in;
}

.example-leave {
    opacity: 1;
}

.example-leave.example-leave-active {
    opacity: 0.01;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in;
}


.example-appear {
    opacity: 0.01;
}

.example-appear.example-appear-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? Latest is using a slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 11):

You're using the version 2 CSSTransition component but are passing it version 1's prop names. If you look in your console you'll probably see warnings that React doesn't recognize 'transitionName', 'transitionAppear', etc.

Here's a way to accomplish what you're looking for using version 2's `CSSTransition` component.

```
<CSSTransition
  classNames="example"
  timeout={500}
  in={this.state.mounted}
>
  <Login/>
</CSSTransition>
```

By default the `CSSTransition` component doesn't run `enter` animations on page load, so you need to set the `in` prop to some arbitrary value that starts out as false but is set to true on `componentDidMount`. Here's a CodeSandbox so you can see the full implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/v8w3jxo94l

Comment: "set the in prop to some arbitrary value that starts out as false but is set to true on componentDidMount." -- This is what I was missing in my code.